# Excel file does not load in MS access

Tags: vba, ms-access

It runs without any Error message but the files are not loaded in MS access.  what could be the reason? I do have a csv file in the directory

After edit

```
Option Compare Database
```

Option Explicit

Public Function import_date_files()

```
Dim report_path As String, file_name As String




report_path = "C:\Users\gobro7\MS access test\weekly_load\"

file_name = Dir(report_path & "*.xlsx")


Do While file_name <> vbNullString
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , Trim(Replace(file_name, ".xlsx", "")), report_path & file_name, True
    file_name = Dir
Loop

MsgBox "Data loaded", vbInformation
```

End Function

Comment: You are missing a backslash between your path and the filename - therefore probably no file is found (something that it easy to check using the debugger). Also, the `Directory`-Option makes no sense as you want to list files, not folders. Change the line to `file_name = Dir(report_path & "\*.csv")`

Comment: since I changed it gives me error again, pointing on `docmd ` line

Comment: You added the backslash there also?

Comment: yes, I have added

Comment: I edited the post you can take a look, not sure if it makes any sense but when i opened the module it did not have `Option Explicit` so I added. In the video they explained it had

Comment: Oooh, never mind, I added the backslash on the path after the  `weekly-load`. So it does not need any back slash on `csv`. thanks for the inspiration tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a backslash between the path and the file name. You can either write

```
file_name = Dir(report_path & "\*.csv")
Do While file_name <> vbNullString
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , Trim(Replace(file_name, ".csv", "")), report_path & "\" & file_name, True
    file_name = Dir
Loop
```

Or you add the backslash at the end of your path definition:

```
' Note the trailing backslash!
report_path = "C:\Users\gobro7\OneDrive - Levi Strauss & Co\MS access test\weekly_load\"

file_name = Dir(report_path & "*.csv")
Do While file_name <> vbNullString
    DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , Trim(Replace(file_name, ".csv", "")), report_path & file_name, True
    file_name = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already done. I marked yours as a correct answer.

Comment: What could be a problem if I change the csv into xlsx because I get the debug error again on `docmd`?

Comment: you can check the new version of the code, I edited